# Mathjax and image descriptions interact inconsistently between the edit preview and actual post

Tags: bug, latex

When trying to edit the image description in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/901/66833) to

> diagram showing an inclined plane at angle \$α\$ and an angry bird being fired at angle \$β\$ at speed \$u\$,

<sup>(raw text is `diagram showing an inclined plane at angle \$α\$ and an angry bird being fired at angle \$β\$ at speed \$u\$`)</sup>

the edit preview shows

[image: edit preview showing a normal post]

whereas if I save the edit, the post instead looks like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/901/8):

[image: image showing the text from the first Mathjax symbol being shown next to the image in the post]

Note the bit of the image description immediately before the first `\$` is shown next to the image (and that the first bit of Mathjax, `\$\alpha\$`, is rendered).

Comment: [Related post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327908/355458)